# LCD screen damaged?

Tags: hardware-failure, lcd

I have an ASUS Laptop. Recently I *may* have sat on it, accidentally.  I freaked out as soon as I heard something crack.  My screen has little cracks in the top left corner, kinda look like a firework exploded on paper.

Very little black mark, so the LCD seemed fine, I thought it might have been the protective layer damaged, so I ignored it, and prayed it would be fine. Two days later the very few black marks decided to cry with me, I now have thin black streaks dropping from the cracks. Screen works fine if I can scroll those cracks out of the way, but I am worried once again, because I heard about LCD fluid leaking into computer hard drives, and my laptop is my baby, my life, my reason for living!  If I loose it I'm joining the freaking army!

So... thoughts?  Help would be nice.

Comment: It's not leaking.  You'd know if it was leaking.  The LCD substrate is damaged, but the whole shebang is hermetically sealed, so unless you have a severe puncture it's fine.

Answer (score 2):

First, remain calm.  No need to sweat too much. There will be a financial cost naturally Check Ebay for  same model with damage to other parts and a good screen.  Check with reseller for a new secreen.  Check online for a used screen

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to my roomate a few years back. Except he had his laptop sitting on the floor and two of the drunk white girls he had in bed with him stumbled out and stepped on it. He didn't cry because he wanted to 'act tough' but did end up removing the hinges and replacing the LCD. If you have the model number, it would help in case if we have/find any literature on dis-assembly.

It is really easy and most laptops follow the same basic concept. They have hinges that have a snapping cover. You may need to remove the top part of the laptop and the keyboard to access the ribbon plugin as well as the screws that may be there for the hinges. Once you remove the hinges and the ribbon connecting the LCD, you should be able to take off the frame of the LCD and put the new one in. Reassemble. Don't sit on or let drunk white girls sit on. Win and not join freakin army :)

Comment: "Don't sit on or let drunk white girls set[sic] on." So drunk girls with different skin color can sit on laptops without damage?

Comment: Could easily also ask, 'So white girls with different BAC levels can sit on laptops without damage.' Why pick out the race? :)

Comment: I asked you first.

Answer (score 1):

As Dave M says, changing the screen is possible.  It's sometimes a bit fiddly, but being methodical and organised helps.

Here's a link to someone repairing a laptop screen. (http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-Asus-V6800V-Display/3394/1)  There are probably other guides on that site too, and there are probably videos online of people changing the screen.

If you really can't repair the screen you buy a new portable machine, and use the broken laptop with a monitor.  Second machines are always useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need a new display. The cracks are going to get bigger and worse. I don't think it's much of a threat to the rest of the laptop, but you'll want to make sure your backups are up to date so that you don't have to do so much work if you need a new one.

Answer (score 0):

LCD fluid is highly unlikely to cause problems. Just don't worry about that particular issue.

Replacing the screen from a used system can be pretty cheap fix, as others have mentioned above.